# UITableView scrolling when Keyboard hides UITextview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, keyboard

I have an issue with my custom UITableViewController. I'm creating one during "viewDidLoad" and begin adding custom cells to it. If I touch a cell with a UITextfield and start editing, the keyboard covers this cell.
So far I have read that this is because I habe added my tableview programmatically. There are a few solutions, that listen to the keyboard events and then scroll the tableview manually, but I have found a behaviour, that I want to take advantage of.
So far: Creating tableview, no automatic scrolling.
On different occasions, I need to push a modal view. After dismissing this view: Everything works. I have a Textfield cell at the bottom of the screen and when I click it, the keyboard pushes the cell up.

Now here is the big question: What happens during this simple push and dismiss?

Comment: tl;dr. Some code would be useful I think. And try to use notifications

Comment: Another mystery from the ModalView & animation series, hope they will update the documentation of that topic sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those strange things that I got stuck on for ages and although I'm not quite sure why the keyboard will scroll for modal and not push, one way to get around it is to use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding). This is a simple fix, however you do need to use a xib file with the tableview in it.